# Revolution Slider Stop After User Interaction

Tags: jquery

I am using this slider on my homepage: http://www.orbis-ingenieria.com/code/documentation/documentation.html#!/documenter_cover

Currently I have the option to pause the slide when a user hovers their mouse over it, but when the mouse is removed the slide continues to play.

I want any user interaction including: hovering and clicking on the slide to result in the slide stopping on whatever slide the user is on. Then when the user takes their mouse away from the slide it SHOULD NOT resume.

Can some one figure this out?

This is the live page: http://searchtransparency.net/air/slider.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
$('.sliderClass').on('hover click', function(){
    sliderInstance.revpause();
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. Maybe I implemented it wrong? This is the live page: http://searchtransparency.net/air/slider.html

Comment: **sliderInstance** was just an example variable name. In your case it would be **api**.

Comment: I changed it to api, but still no success :(

Comment: $('.banner-simple').on('click mouseenter', function(e){api.revpause();});